# Kubernetes configMap - only one file

Tags: kubernetes

I have a `configMap` created from file:

```
kubectl create configmap ssportal-apache-conf --from-file=ssportal.conf=ssportal.conf
```

and then I need to mount this file into the deployment:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: ssportal
spec:
  replicas: 2
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: ssportal
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: ssportal
          image: eu.gcr.io/my-project/ssportal:0.0.0
          ports:
          - containerPort: 80
          volumeMounts:
            - name: apache2-config-volume
              mountPath: /etc/apache2/
      volumes:
        - name: apache2-config-volume
          configMap:
            name: ssportal-apache-conf
            items:
              - key: ssportal.conf
                path: sites-enabled/ssportal.conf
```

But this effectively removes the existing `/etc/apache2/` directory from the container and replaces it with one an only file `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/ssportal.conf`.

Is it possible to overlay only one file over the existing config directory?

Answer (score 34):

Okay, it's a bit tricky. The final working YAML spec is

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: ssportal
spec:
  replicas: 2
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: ssportal
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: ssportal
          image: eu.gcr.io/my-project/ssportal:0.0.0
          command: ["sleep","120d"]
          ports:
          - containerPort: 80
          volumeMounts:
            - name: test
              mountPath: /etc/apache2/conf-enabled/test.conf
              subPath: test.conf
      volumes:
        - name: test
          configMap:
            name: sstest
```

and `configMap` creation steps:

```
echo "# comment" > test.conf
kubectl create configmap sstest --from-file=test.conf=test.conf
```

Comment: Also, just on the side note, `kubectl create configmap sstest --from-file=test.conf` is sufficient for creating configmap.

Answer (score 17):

This works for me too. Useful in case you have more than one file inside the configmap.

```
            volumeMounts:
            - name: test
              mountPath: /etc/apache2/conf-enabled/test.conf
              subPath: test.conf
      volumes:
        - name: test
          configMap:
            name: test
            - key: test.conf
              path: test.conf
```

Comment: If the original container has more files in /etc/apache2/conf-enabled/ those won't be affected?

Answer (score 10):

Yes. In `volumeMounts` set `subPath: ssportal.conf` and `mountPath: /etc/apache2/ssportal.conf`. You may remove the `items: ...` too.

Read more here: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#using-subpath