# Are you trying to mount a directory onto a file (or vice-versa) with kuberneters/configMap?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, prometheus, kubectl, minikube

I followed this post [Kubernetes configMap - only one file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44325048/kubernetes-configmap-only-one-file) to pass a config file to a deployment, but got an error. Why?

The config file `config-prom-prometheus.yml`:

```
scrape_configs:
- job_name: job-leo-prometheus
  kubernetes_sd_configs:
  - role: endpoints
```

The .yaml file `prom-prometheus.yaml`:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: prom-prometheus-deployment
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: prom-prometheus
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: prom-prometheus
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: prom-prometheus
        image: 127.0.0.1:30400/prom/prometheus
        ports:
        - name: port9090
          containerPort: 9090
        volumeMounts:
        - name: volume-prometheus
          mountPath: /etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml
          subPath: prometheus.yml
      volumes:
      - name: volume-prometheus
        configMap:
          name: config-prom

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: prom-prometheus
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - name: port9090
    protocol: TCP
    port: 9090
    targetPort: 9090
    nodePort: 30090
  selector:
    app: prom-prometheus
```

Commands:

```
kubectl create configmap config-prom --from-file=config-prom-prometheus.yml
kubectl -f prom-prometheus.yaml apply
```

Results:

```
Events:
  Type     Reason                 Age               From               Message
  ----     ------                 ----              ----               -------
  Normal   Scheduled              17s               default-scheduler  Successfully assigned prom-prometheus-deployment-66887dcdbf-bfqd4 to minikube
  Normal   SuccessfulMountVolume  17s               kubelet, minikube  MountVolume.SetUp succeeded for volume "default-token-ml6w5"
  Normal   SuccessfulMountVolume  17s               kubelet, minikube  MountVolume.SetUp succeeded for volume "volume-prometheus"
  Warning  Failed                 9s                kubelet, minikube  Error: failed to start container "prom-prometheus": Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:348: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:402: container init caused \"rootfs_linux.go:58: mounting \\\"/var/lib/kubelet/pods/ec99da92-e994-11e8-a578-08002742f2a3/volume-subpaths/volume-prometheus/prom-prometheus/0\\\" to rootfs \\\"/var/lib/docker/overlay2/12c7da1c07c55fe2ec5dff61e5c457fa8aeaa32d47232c28a1d7e127c4f81bf0/merged\\\" at \\\"/var/lib/docker/overlay2/12c7da1c07c55fe2ec5dff61e5c457fa8aeaa32d47232c28a1d7e127c4f81bf0/merged/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml\\\" caused \\\"not a directory\\\"\"": unknown: Are you trying to mount a directory onto a file (or vice-versa)? Check if the specified host path exists and is the expected type
  Normal   Pulling                7s (x2 over 13s)  kubelet, minikube  pulling image "127.0.0.1:30400/prom/prometheus"
  Normal   Pulled                 7s (x2 over 13s)  kubelet, minikube  Successfully pulled image "127.0.0.1:30400/prom/prometheus"
  Normal   Created                6s (x2 over 10s)  kubelet, minikube  Created container
  Warning  Failed                 4s                kubelet, minikube  Error: failed to start container "prom-prometheus": Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:348: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:402: container init caused \"rootfs_linux.go:58: mounting \\\"/var/lib/kubelet/pods/ec99da92-e994-11e8-a578-08002742f2a3/volume-subpaths/volume-prometheus/prom-prometheus/0\\\" to rootfs \\\"/var/lib/docker/overlay2/7b07728ae4439e4d479386eab6b042948e2cb586c54171941f24d03352a7c8b4/merged\\\" at \\\"/var/lib/docker/overlay2/7b07728ae4439e4d479386eab6b042948e2cb586c54171941f24d03352a7c8b4/merged/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml\\\" caused \\\"not a directory\\\"\"": unknown: Are you trying to mount a directory onto a file (or vice-versa)? Check if the specified host path exists and is the expected type
```

Comment: try mountPath: /etc/prometheus/config-prom-prometheus.yml and subPath: config-prom-prometheus.yml.

Comment: or rename config-prom-prometheus.yml to prometheus.yml

Comment: @VKR, the 2nd way worked. Can you please create an answer? I will accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is not well documented but as per my experience name of configmap yaml (config-prom-prometheus.yml in your case) should be the same as `mountPath` and `subPath` in `Deployment`.

If you use `subPath: prometheus.yml` - rename `config-prom-prometheus.yml` to `prometheus.yml` and try again.

Answer (score 9):

This is probably slightly rewording the accepted answer, but one thing that confused me was that the mount path expected *full* path of to the target file.

`subPath` is the key in the volume (e.g. config map) for the source.

`mountPath` is target full path for the file.

For some reason my brain was thinking `mountPath` was the target directory and the `subPath` would infer the target file name.  All I had to do was add the filename at the end of the `mountPath`.

For example:

**Bad:**

```
- name: config-volume
  mountPath: "/opt/config/path/"
  subPath: "config-file.json"
```

**Good:**

```
- name: config-volume
  mountPath: "/opt/config/path/config-file.json"
  subPath: "config-file.json"
```