# Kubernetes: Replace file by configmap

Tags: kubernetes

Here my configmap:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
    name: chart-1591249502-zeppelin
    namespace: ra-iot-dev
    labels:
        helm.sh/chart: zeppelin-0.1.0
        app.kubernetes.io/name: zeppelin
        app.kubernetes.io/instance: chart-1591249502
        app.kubernetes.io/version: "0.9.0"
        app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
data:
  log4j.properties: |-
    log4j.rootLogger = INFO, dailyfile
    log4j.appender.stdout = org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
    log4j.appender.stdout.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
    log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%5p [%d] ({%t} %F[%M]:%L) - %m%n
    log4j.appender.dailyfile.DatePattern=.yyyy-MM-dd
    log4j.appender.dailyfile.DEBUG = INFO
    log4j.appender.dailyfile = org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
    log4j.appender.dailyfile.File = ${zeppelin.log.file}
    log4j.appender.dailyfile.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
    log4j.appender.dailyfile.layout.ConversionPattern=%5p [%d] ({%t} %F[%M]:%L) - %m%n
    log4j.logger.org.apache.zeppelin.python=DEBUG
    log4j.logger.org.apache.zeppelin.spark=DEBUG
```

I'm trying to mount this file into `/zeppelin/conf/log4j.properties` pod directory file.

Here my deployment:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: chart-1591249502-zeppelin
  labels:
    helm.sh/chart: zeppelin-0.1.0
    app.kubernetes.io/name: zeppelin
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: chart-1591249502
    app.kubernetes.io/version: "0.9.0"
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app.kubernetes.io/name: zeppelin
      app.kubernetes.io/instance: chart-1591249502
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app.kubernetes.io/name: zeppelin
        app.kubernetes.io/instance: chart-1591249502
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: chart-1591249502-zeppelin
      securityContext:
        {}
      containers:
        - name: zeppelin
          securityContext:
            {}
          image: "apache/zeppelin:0.9.0"
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          ports:
            - name: http
              containerPort: 8080
              protocol: TCP
          livenessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /
              port: http
          readinessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /
              port: http
          resources:
            {}
          env:
            - name: ZEPPELIN_PORT
              value: "8080"
            - name: ZEPPELIN_K8S_CONTAINER_IMAGE
              value: apache/zeppelin:0.9.0
            - name: ZEPPELIN_RUN_MODE
              value: local
          volumeMounts:
            - name: log4j-properties-volume
              mountPath: /zeppelin/conf/log4j.properties
      volumes:
        - name: log4j-properties-volume
          configMap:
            name: chart-1591249502-zeppelin
            items:
              - key: log4j.properties
                path: keys
```

I'm getting this error event in kubernetes:

> Error: failed to start container "zeppelin": Error response from daemon: oci runtime error: container_linux.go:247: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:364: container init caused \"rootfs_linux.go:54: mounting \\"/var/lib/origin/openshift.local.volumes/pods/63ac209e-a626-11ea-9e39-0050569f5f65/volumes/kubernetes.io~configmap/log4j-properties-volume\\" to rootfs \\"/var/lib/docker/overlay2/33f3199e46111afdcd64d21c58b010427c27761b02473967600fb95ab6d92e21/merged\\" at \\"/var/lib/docker/overlay2/33f3199e46111afdcd64d21c58b010427c27761b02473967600fb95ab6d92e21/merged/zeppelin/conf/log4j.properties\\" caused \\"not a directory\\"\"" : Are you trying to mount a directory onto a file (or vice-versa)? Check if the specified host path exists and is the expected type

Take in mind, that I only want to replace an existing file. I mean, into `/zeppelin/conf/` directory there are several files. I only want to replace `/zeppelin/conf/log4j.properties`.

Any ideas?

Comment: Check the answer for this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53338042/are-you-trying-to-mount-a-directory-onto-a-file-or-vice-versa-with-kuberneters.

Comment: There are 2 things. Using `SubPath` in your `spec.containers.volumeMounts` and also issue with `namespace` (ConfigMap is in `namespace: ra-iot-dev` and deployment is in default. Writing answer with wider explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From logs I saw that you are working on `OpenShift`, however I was able to do it on `GKE`.

I've deployed pure zeppelin deployment form your example.

```
zeppelin@chart-1591249502-zeppelin-557d895cd5-v46dt:~/conf$ cat log4j.properties
#
# Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
...
# the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
...
# limitations under the License.
#

log4j.rootLogger = INFO, stdout

log4j.appender.stdout = org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%5p [%d] ({%t} %F[%M]:%L) - %m%n
zeppelin@chart-1591249502-zeppelin-557d895cd5-v46dt:~/conf$
```

If you want to repleace one specific file, you need to use [subPath](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#using-subpath). There is also article with another example which can be found [here](https://carlos.mendible.com/2019/02/10/kubernetes-mount-file-pod-with-configmap/).

**Issue 1. ConfigMap belongs to `namespace`**

Your deployment did not contains any namespace so it was deployed in `default` namespace. `ConfigMap` included `namespace: ra-iot-dev`.

```
$ kubectl api-resources
NAME                              SHORTNAMES   APIGROUP                       NAMESPACED   KIND
...
configmaps                        cm                                          true         ConfigMap
...
```

If you will keep this namespace, you will probably get error like:

```
MountVolume.SetUp failed for volume "log4j-properties-volume" : configmap "chart-1591249502-zeppelin" not found
```

**Issue 2. subPath to replace file**

Ive changed one part in `deployment` (added `subPath`)

```
    volumeMounts:
      - name: log4j-properties-volume
        mountPath: /zeppelin/conf/log4j.properties
        subPath: log4j.properties
volumes:
  - name: log4j-properties-volume
    configMap:
      name: chart-1591249502-zeppelin
```

and another in `ConfigMap` (removed namespace and set proper names)

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
    name: chart-1591249502-zeppelin
    labels:
        helm.sh/chart: zeppelin-0.1.0
        app.kubernetes.io/name: zeppelin
        app.kubernetes.io/instance: chart-1591249502
        app.kubernetes.io/version: "0.9.0"
        app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
data:
  log4j.properties: |-
...
```

After that output of the file looks like:

```
$ kubectl exec -ti chart-1591249502-zeppelin-64495dcfc8-ccddr -- /bin/bash
zeppelin@chart-1591249502-zeppelin-64495dcfc8-ccddr:~$ cd conf
zeppelin@chart-1591249502-zeppelin-64495dcfc8-ccddr:~/conf$ ls
configuration.xsl  log4j.properties   log4j_yarn_cluster.properties  zeppelin-env.cmd.template  zeppelin-site.xml.template
interpreter-list   log4j.properties2  shiro.ini.template             zeppelin-env.sh.template
zeppelin@chart-1591249502-zeppelin-64495dcfc8-ccddr:~/conf$ cat log4j.properties
log4j.rootLogger = INFO, dailyfile
log4j.appender.stdout = org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%5p [%d] ({%t} %F[%M]:%L) - %m%n
log4j.appender.dailyfile.DatePattern=.yyyy-MM-dd
log4j.appender.dailyfile.DEBUG = INFO
log4j.appender.dailyfile = org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.dailyfile.File = ${zeppelin.log.file}
log4j.appender.dailyfile.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.dailyfile.layout.ConversionPattern=%5p [%d] ({%t} %F[%M]:%L) - %m%n
log4j.logger.org.apache.zeppelin.python=DEBUG
log4j.logger.org.apache.zeppelin.spark=DEBUGzeppelin@chart-1591249502-zeppelin-64495dcfc8-ccddr:~/conf$
```

Answer (score 0):

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: application-config-test
  namespace: ***
  labels:
    app: test
    environment: ***
    tier: backend
data:
  application.properties: |-
    ulff.kafka.configuration.acks=0
    ulff.kafka.configuration[bootstrap.servers]=IP
    ulff.kafka.topic=test-topic
    ulff.enabled=true
    logging.level.com.anurag.gigthree.ulff.kafka=DEBUG

    management.port=9080
    management.security.enabled=false 
    management.endpoints.web.exposure.include= "metrics,health,threaddump,prometheus,heapdump"
    management.endpoint.prometheus.enabled=true
    management.metrics.export.prometheus.enabled=true
    ## For apigee PROD
    apigee.url=****   
    
    ### Secrets in Kubenetes accessed by ENV variables
    apigee.clientID=apigeeClientId
    apigee.clientsecret=apigeeClientSecret

    spring.mvc.throw-exception-if-no-handler-found=true

    #For OAuth details for apigee
    oauth2.config.clientId=${apigee.clientID}
    oauth2.config.clientSecret=${apigee.clientsecret}
    oauth2.config.authenticationScheme=form
    oauth2.config.scopes[0]=test_INTEGRATION_ALL
    oauth2.config.accessTokenUri=${apigee.url}/oauth2/token
    oauth2.config.requestTimeout=55000

    oauth2.restTemplateBuilder.enabled=true

    #spring jackson properties
    spring.jackson.default-property-inclusion=always
    spring.jackson.generator.ignore-unknown=true
    spring.jackson.mapper.accept-case-insensitive-properties=true
    spring.jackson.deserialization.fail-on-unknown-properties=false

    # service urls for apply profile
    services.apigeeIntegrationAPI.doProfileChangeUrl=${apigee.url}/v1/testintegration
    services.apigeeIntegrationAPI.modifyServiceOfSubscriberUrl=${apigee.url}/v1/testintegration/subscribers

    # service urls for retrieve profile
    services.apigeeIntegrationAPI.getProfileUrl=${apigee.url}/v1
    services.apigeeIntegrationAPI.readKeyUrl=${apigee.url}/v1/testintegration

   

    

    test.acfStatusConfig[1].country-prefix=
    test.acfStatusConfig[1].country-code=
    test.acfStatusConfig[1].profile-name=
    test.acfStatusConfig[1].adult=ON
    test.acfStatusConfig[1].hvw=ON
    test.acfStatusConfig[1].ms=ON
    test.acfStatusConfig[1].dc=ON
    test.acfStatusConfig[1].at=OFF
    test.acfStatusConfig[1].gambling=
    test.acfStatusConfig[1].dating=OFF
    test.acfStatusConfig[1].sex=OFF
    test.acfStatusConfig[1].sn=OFF


    logging.pattern.level=%X{ulff.transaction-id:-} -%5p
    logging.config=/app/config/log4j2.yml
  log4j2.yml: |-
    Configutation:
      name: test-ms
      packages : 
      Appenders:
        Console:
          - name: sysout
            target: SYSTEM_OUT
            PatternLayout:
              pattern: "%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5p [%-7t] %F:%L - %m%n"
          - name: syserr
            target: SYSTEM_ERR
            PatternLayout:
              pattern: "%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5p [%-7t] %F:%L - %m%n"
            Filters:
              ThresholdFilter :
                level: "WARN"
                onMatch: "ACCEPT"
        Kafka:
          name : kafkaAppender
          topic: af.prod.ms.test.tomcat
          JSONLayout:
            complete: "false"
            compact: "false"
            eventEol: "true"
            includeStacktrace: "true"
            properties: "true"
          Property:
            name: "bootstrap.servers"
            value: ""
      Loggers:
        Root:
          level: INFO
          AppenderRef:
           - ref: sysout
           - ref: syserr
        #### test 1 test 2 Separate kafka log from application log
        Logger:
          - name: com.anurag
            level: INFO
            AppenderRef:
              - ref: kafkaAppender
          - name: org.springframework
            level: INFO
            AppenderRef:
              - ref: kafkaAppender
```